# Laravel 5.8 saving one to many relation on pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a many to many relation with a pivot table. In this pivot table I have 2 one to many relations. It looks like this drawn out:

[image]

In code it looks like this:

WorkflowStep model:

```php
public function workflowinstances(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(WorkflowInstance::class)
        ->using(WorkflowInstanceWorkflowStep::class)
        ->withPivot([
            'started_at',
            'finished_at',
            'failed_at',
            'output',
        ])
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

WorkflowInstance model:

```php
public function workflowSteps(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(WorkflowStep::class)
        ->using(WorkflowInstanceWorkflowStep::class)
        ->withPivot([
            'started_at',
            'finished_at',
            'failed_at',
            'output',
        ])
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

WorkflowInstanceWorkflowStep Pivot model:

```php
public function sourceFile(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(File::class, 'source_file_id', 'id');
}

public function destinationFile(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(File::class, 'destination_file_id', 'id');
}
```

File model:

```php
public function workflowInstanceStepSources(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(WorkflowInstanceWorkflowStep::class, 'source_file_id', 'id');
}

public function workflowInstanceStepDestinations(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(WorkflowInstanceWorkflowStep::class, 'destination_file_id', 'id');
}
```

Now My goals is to save the file - pivot relation but this doesn't seem to be working:

```php
$fileObject = $workflowStep->entity->sourceClient->files()->create([
    'name' => $filename,
    'extension' => $file['extension'],
    'category' => 'transfer',
    'original_file_id' => 1,
    'path' => $filePath,
    'link_id' => 1,
]);

$fileObject->workflowInstanceStepSources()->save();
```

I create a new File object and then I want to link it to the pivot table with my relation

Is what I am trying here even possible?

EDIT complete db scheme

[image]

Comment: May you add the code around your `save` to understand the context please?

Comment: @Shizzen83 I edited the original post

Comment: Not an answer but question, how do you generate such beautiful diagrams?

Comment: @Shobi https://drawsql.app/ :)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to save the model and its relationships, try the `push` method instead of `save`, it recursively saves.

```php
$fileObject->push();
```

Comment: shoudn't I define what I wanna push?

Comment: I can't see your `entity` and `sourceClient` implementations. `entity` looks like a polymorphic relationship but I don't see anything about `sourceClient`.